# What visa do my wife and infant daughter need to travel to the UK to meet me, if I'm going there on a business visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a resident of India and just got a UK business visa (6 months, multiple entry).  I am going for 3 months on a business trip. I want to take my wife and daughter (10 months old) for the last 2 months to stay with me. The purpose of their visit is to stay with me as my baby is very close to me.  We are planning to visit different locations in the UK too.

My company is providing accommodation to me, but I am planning to rent a home to stay with my family after 1 month, once they will reach the UK.

What visa should I apply for for my wife and daughter?  Is it the visitor visa?  Should she mention in the visa form that she is going to stay with me while I am on a business visa?

I am not sure about the below points; can any one please let me know?

1) While I am on a business visa, is my family allowed to stay with me?

2) Will I able to rent a house in UK during my stay?

3) While they are applying for their visas, what should they mention in the visa application, as still now their accommodation is not confirmed?  Once I reach the UK, I will arrange it for them.  I am traveling in September, and they plan to come UK in October.

4) I want to complete their visa before I leave for the UK.

My daughter is very close to me.  I need them in the UK as 3 months without seeing her is tough for me.

Comment: Is your visa a standard visitor visa or some other type of visa?

Comment: My visa is business visa for 6 months multiple entry

Comment: The UK does not have a visa called "business visa."  The *Standard Visitor Visa* can be issued to certain business visitors.  Is that what you have?

Comment: That's correct it's visit-business-6months

Comment: Rentals for as short a period as two months tend to be more expensive than longer term rentals. You should consider talking to your company about accomodation. It may be easier for them to find accomodation suitable for three of you, and for you to pay the difference in cost back to them.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) While I am on a business visa, is my family allowed to stay with me?

Yes, if their visas are granted.

> 2) Will I able to rent a house in UK during my stay?

There is surely some sort of accommodation available for short term family visitors, but I do not know about the price and availability.  You will need to find out about this *before* you apply for your family's visas, however, because the visas will only be granted if you can show that you can afford the cost of their trip.  You can't expect to show that if you don't know how much the trip will cost.

> 3) While they are applying for their visas, what should they mention in the visa application, as still now their accommodation is not confirmed? Once I reach the UK, I will arrange it for them. I am traveling in September, and they plan to come UK in October.

You should arrange their accommodation before you submit their visa applications.  The applications will otherwise run a much higher risk of being refused.

> 4) I want to complete their visa before I leave for the UK.

Then, as mentioned above, you should arrange accommodation for their visit before you leave for the UK.

Comment: Thank you so much so ur response. I must appreciate your response to guide me in better way. I am planning to book a hotel with zero cancellation fees for them in any random date for their visa application. Once their visa is confirmed then I will rent a house for us in UK.  Is this way worthy. More I will be glad if you can guide me what are the documents from my end they need to process their visa application. I am not that much aware for this. So looking for ur advise.  I hope I you will nt mind

Comment: I hope you will not mind to help me.

Comment: Hiii did u get a chance to c my thought against your suggestion

Comment: @Krish making a booking that you don't intend to use is probably not a great idea.  If you're found out, it will appear as if you're trying to do something improper.  A far better approach will be to do the extra work required to find an appropriate accommodation before you depart.  As to the documents required, that is covered on [the UK's own site](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide).  Be sure to follow the links to the other pages with more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you... yes before I leave I will arrange the proper accommodation for them may be I will rent a house in advance for them. Really thank you so much for your all help and support. I will be in touch with u and let u know further update.

Comment: @phoog- one good news .. my company is providing accommodation to my family for 45 days along with me. They are proving a 2BHK service apartment to us. Hence I am proceeding with their application. Just one quick query. What are my documents they require to submit along with their application. Will be glad if you share some list with me.

Comment: @Krish if the information in the link in my previous comment is inadequate, please post a [new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to seek clarification.

Comment: I posted my new question regarding the list of documents, can you please help me out. Link is-   https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/100937/66813